# How to redirect multiple domains to another domain except 1 directory using htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, directory

I am trying to redirect multiple domains to a single domain (which is working fine)
but i want one directory to not redirect or change the main domain url.

here is my .htaccess code it works fine until here

**this one is working**

```
<pre>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^http(s)?://(www.)?domain.com$  [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^http(s)?://(www.)?domain.net$  [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^http(s)?://(www.)?domain.org$  [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^domain.info$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^www.domain.info
    RewriteRule (.*)    http://www.domain.info/$1   [R=301,L]
</pre>
```

but when i try to stop redirect of one specific directory by

**full code**

```
<pre>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^http(s)?://(www.)?domain.com$  [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^http(s)?://(www.)?domain.net$  [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^http(s)?://(www.)?domain.org$  [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^domain.info$        [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^www.domain.info   [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/no_redirect_dir/
    RewriteRule (.*)    http://www.domain.info/$1   [R=301,L]
</pre>
```

it all stops working :( with an error that page is not redirecting correctly.

**extra code causing error**

```
<pre>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^www.domain.info   [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/no_redirect_dir/
</pre>
```

any help would be highly appreciated.

thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Write your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?domain\.(org|net|com)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/*no_redirect_dir/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.info/$1 [R=301,L]
```

HTTP_HOST variable just has domain name, no http/https information.